# Get the MAC address of an XBee using Node.js

Tags: node.js, xbee, node-serialport, node-xbee

My Node.js app is using `xbee-api` to allow an XBee connected via a serial port to communicate wirelessly with other XBees. The local XBee is in API Coordinator mode.

How can I query the XBee (physically connected via serial port) to get its 64 bit [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) `SH` and `SL`?

I tried writing the following frame to serial,

```
var frame_obj = {
    type: xbee_api.constants.FRAME_TYPE.AT_COMMAND,
    command: 'SH',
      commandParameter: []
};
```

but I receive four bytes `[ 0, 19, 162, 0 ]` which makes no sense...

```
frame: { type: 136,
   id: 2,
   command: 'SH',
   commandStatus: 0,
   commandData: [ 0, 19, 162, 0 ] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the bytes in hex (0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00), it does make sense.